# Display a single row from nested array of custom field data

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, array

I built an Exercise custom post type with a custom field group using Advanced Custom Fields. The structure uses repeater fields for Week, Day, and Exercise, which creates a series of nested arrays. It looks like this:

Week 1
-- Day 1
---- Exercise 1
---- Exercise 2
-- Day 2
---- Exercise 1
---- Exercise 2
-- Day 3
---- Exercise 1
---- Exercise 2
Week 2
-- Day 1
---- Exercise 1
---- Exercise 2
-- Day 2
---- Exercise 1
---- Exercise 2
-- Day 3
---- Exercise 1
---- Exercise 2

I am able to display all of the contents using nested while loops, but what I want to do is display a singe Day's exercises.

The final page will look like this:

Week 2
Day 3
List of exercises

I have tried different ways to limit output, including using a counter, but that only allows me to stop after X rows. I tried using array_slice, which worked fine on the outer most array level for Weeks, but did not work on the inner arrays.

Any idea how I can display a specific day?

Comment: My question may be a bit messy. Let me simplify: I have a multidimensional array that is 5 layers deep; post, week, day, exercises, sets. I want to be able to display the contents of the array week 1, day 1, and all exercises and sets in the day 1 row.

Comment: What does the array look like if you `var_dump( $your_array )`?

Comment: I actually figured out a way to make it work, though not very clean. Then I figured out the right way; using "while" loop an "if" statement and a counter I was able to get it to work. I will post the code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using a While loop and an If statement with a counter. This solution uses functions from Advanced Custom Fields;

```
$i = 0;  
while have_rows('week_rows') ): the_row();  
  $i++;  

  if( $i == 5 ) {  // stops on the 5th row of 'week_rows' array
    break;  
  }  

endwhile; // I had to move the endwhile up before my display statements 

// add display statements here to display array contents from 5th array row

?>
```

Comment: This also works on deeper layers of a multi-dimensional array. In my case I used it to set the "Week" row, and then in the next dimension, to set the "Day" row.